# HAProxy load balancer: Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I just setup a load balancer with HAProxy 1.5.2, and the HTTPS frontend work incorrectly.

I use curl to make an request to my server as follow:
*curl https://haproxy.example.com*
The output as follows:

> curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
>   More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>   curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
>    of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
>    bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
>    using the --cacert option.
>   If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
>    the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
>    problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
>    not match the domain name in the URL).
>   If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
>    the -k (or --insecure) option.

The following are the configuration:

> frontend https-in
>    **bind *:443 ssl crt /var/crt/mycrt.pem ca-file /var/crt/myca.crt**
>    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
>    default_backend https-in-443

The */var/crt/myca.crt* are the CA bundle file.

Anybody can help on this issue? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i fixed this issue

Just added "verify optional" to the end of **bind *:443 ssl crt /var/crt/mycrt.pem ca-file /var/crt/myca.txt** as follow

Reference: [HAProxy: client side ssl certificates](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/haproxy_client_side_ssl_certificates.html#Sending_certificate_details_to_backend_application)

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing. Where did you get the myca.txt from. I followed the instructions at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-ssl-termination-with-haproxy-on-ubuntu-14-04 and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04#StepTwo%E2%80%94CreateaSelf-SignedSSLCertificate to create the self signed certificate. I also tried to add `verify optional` at the end of bind line, however i still get the invalid certificate issue. btw my haproxy version is 1.4.24. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @user320550, Actually, the myca.txt is the CA bundle file when you issue the certificate from a CA provider. It contains root and intermediate certificates